# Action Script 3. How to add timer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, timer, flash-cs5

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards. But when I choose 1, if second card is wrong It discover only for half second, but this is not enough. I need to make that second card will be shown for 2-3 seconds. How can I add timer?

Here is part of code:

```
        else
        {
            trace("wrong");
            _message = "wrong";
            message_txt.text = _message;
            _firstCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
            _firstCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
            event.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
            _firstCard = undefined;             
        }
```

Thank you for answers.

**UPDATED WITH FULL CODE**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import Card;
    import Boarder;
    import BlueBoard;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import RedBoard;
    import Snow;

    public class MemoryGame extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _card:Card;
        private var _boarder:Boarder;
        private var _blueBoard:BlueBoard;
        private var _cardX:Number;
        private var _cardY:Number;
        private var _firstCard:*;
        private var _totalMatches:Number;
        private var _currentMatches:Number;
        private var _redBoard:RedBoard;
        private var _snow:Snow;
        private var _cards:Array;
        public var  _message:String;

        public function MemoryGame()
        {
            _cards = new Array();
            _totalMatches = 4;
            _currentMatches = 0;
            createCards();
        }

        private function createCards():void
        {
            _cardX = 45;
            _cardY = 10;

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _boarder = new Boarder();
                _card.setType(_boarder);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            for(var j:Number = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _blueBoard = new BlueBoard();
                _card.setType(_blueBoard);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            _cardX = 45;
            _cardY = _card.height + 30;

            for(var k:Number = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _redBoard = new RedBoard();
                _card.setType(_redBoard);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            for(var l:Number = 0; l < 2; l++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _snow = new Snow();
                _card.setType(_snow);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            randomizeCards(_cards);
        }

        private function checkCards(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);

            if(_firstCard == undefined)
            {
                _firstCard = event.currentTarget;
            }
            else if(String(_firstCard._type) == String(event.currentTarget._type))
            {
                trace("match");
                _message = "match";
                message_txt.text = _message;
                _firstCard = undefined;
                _currentMatches ++;
                if(_currentMatches >= _totalMatches)
                {
                    trace("YOU WIN !!!");
                    _message = "YOU WIN !!!";
                    message_txt.text = _message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                trace("wrong");
                _message = "wrong";
                message_txt.text = _message;
                _firstCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
                event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
                _firstCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                event.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _firstCard = undefined;             
            }
        }

        private function randomizeCards(cards:Array):void
        {
            var randomCard1:Number;
            var randomCard2:Number;
            var card1X:Number;
            var card1Y:Number;

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                randomCard1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
                randomCard2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

                card1X = cards[randomCard1].x;
                card1Y = cards[randomCard1].y;
                cards[randomCard1].x = cards[randomCard2].x;
                cards[randomCard1].y = cards[randomCard2].y
                cards[randomCard2].x = card1X;
                cards[randomCard2].y = card1Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html. BTW, do note that Timer constructor's default 2nd parameter is 0 implying that the timer would run indefinitely. Be sure to mark that as 1 for your case.

You need to move code in your 'else' block to another function and setup the timer instead in the else block.

The final code would look something like this:

```
else
{
    trace("wrong");
    _message = "wrong";
    message_txt.text = _message;

    _secondCard = event.currentTarget;//You need to have this variable defined alongwith _firstCard

    var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, flipBack);
    timer.start();
}
```

and the function would have:

```
protected function flipBack(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    _firstCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
    _sedondCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
    _firstCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
    _secondCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
    _firstCard = _secondCard = undefined;             
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, but I don't understood really where I need to use this constructor. And whats about 2nd parameter? Could you help me a little bit more?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for answers I will try It. I updated my question with full code if you need to see It

Comment: Updated the answer to accommodate more detailed code in question. Also, do note the extra variable _sedondCard that would be required.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This working, but i found 1 error. When 2nd card is shown I can discover 3rd card and I get error. I need to make something like pause/disable discover function while 2nd card is shown. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use _secondFlag!=undefined as a flag to note that checking is on. checkCard function can verify this condition and not do anywhing if it's true. On a sidenote, try to keep one question to one problem. I'd suggesting creating a new question for this. This would keep the site clean and would help the community for one problem per post :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's only to wait a certain amount of time, you can use setTimeout (flash.utils)

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()

Comment: Yes, that It is what I need, but I don't know how to use It correct in my app, after I try, my app doesn't work. I don't get any errors just cards not appear on screen at all.